# Is there a good example of using Active Choices Plugin in declarative pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I would like to use Active Choices plugin for some reasons, and I need it into declarative pipelines (as far as i know it is not available in scripted pipelines). But there isn't a good example how to do this!

I found an example here
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.activeChoiceParam

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        activeChoiceParam('CHOICE-1') {
            description('Allows user choose from multiple choices')
            filterable()
            choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
            groovyScript {
                script('["choice1", "choice2"]')
                fallbackScript('"fallback choice"')
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

But run failures and there is a log:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 5: Build parameters definitions cannot have blocks @ line 5, column 9.
           activeChoiceParam('CHOICE-1') {
           ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Does somebody know a good example of using this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin doesn’t support pipelines yet. The example you have mentioned is for Job DSL and cannot be used in pipelines.

Comment: is this https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.activeChoiceParam outdated? or it never worked?

Comment: @AshishKumar Looks like this example is outdated. I have found this bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55271 that might solve the bug and bring that example back to life. The bug has resolution `Fixed but Unreleased`

Comment: @ymochurad thanks for updating us. It would be great help if you notify us when it is released too(in case we missed).